# Java compiler error "type parameter is not within its bound" with generics

Tags: java, generics

I have 2 related questions:

Codefor question 1:

```
1    private List<OfferEnriched> sortedByDate(List<OfferEnriched> offers) {
2        Collections.sort(offers, new Comparator<OfferEnriched>() {
3            @Override
4            public int compare(OfferEnriched offer1, OfferEnriched offer2) {
5                return offer1.getExDate().compareTo(offer2.getExDate());
6            }
7        });
8        return offers;
9    }
```

Question 1: The error "type parameter xxx.ecom.process.profile.offers.OfferEnriched is not within its bound" is pointed at line 1 and 2 above. What is the problem?

Quetiosn 2: Also at the call of the method I get error: "cannot access xxx.ecom.process.profile.offers.Offer. class file for xxx.ecom.process.profile.offers.Offer not found". Why does the compiler look for Offer in xxx.ecom.process.profile.offers package? See code below.

Code for question 2:

```
    List<OfferEnriched> offers =
        sortedByDate(getOffersHelper().enrichAllOffers(userContext,
            getOffersAdapter().getOffers(market, emailAddr), channelsWeCareAbout));
```

Error is pointed at above statement. 
OffersHelper class is in package xxx.ecom.process.profile.helper and its enrichAllOffers method has following signature:

```
public List<OfferEnriched> enrichAllOffers(UserContext userContext, List<Offer> offers,
    Collection<ChannelType> channelsWeCareAbout)
```

where Offer is in package xxx.profile.common.offers

Any help will be appreciated.
Raj

Comment: Can you provide a short but *complete* program demonstrating the problem? Is this all within a generic type, for example?

Comment: Looks correct,assuming while calling sortedByDate you are giving an input of type List<OfferEnriched>